# Outlook signature valign doesn't work in gmail

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Hello I am making outlook signature and I want to vertical center my text to image.

I have problem with Gmail because it looks like:
See image below.
[Gmail problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhbKO.jpg)

It looks like gmail don't read

```
vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"
```

I've prepared code snippet and here all works good.

```html
<div style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif; margin-left: 15px;">
  <img alt="phone" src="/image006.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></img>
  <span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:right;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
  <br>
  <img alt="fax" src="/image008.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle">
  </img>
  <span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:right;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
  <br>
  <img alt="cell" src="/image010.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle">
  </img>
  <span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:right;">&nbsp 000 000 000</span>
  <br>
  <img alt="mail" src="/image012.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></img>
  <span style="font-size: 11pt; display: inline; text-align:right;">&nbsp name@web.com</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt"><b>Company Name</b></span>
  <br>
  <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt">address</span>
  <br>
  <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt">00000000000</span>
  <br>
  <a style="color:black; text-decoration:none; display: block;" href="http://www.web.com">
    <span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;"><b>www.web.com</b></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When coding for emails you need to stick to tables. I have re-coded your signature to what i think will work in all email clients. Give it a go and let me know if it works.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left: 15px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="3%" align="left" valign="middle"><img alt="phone" src="/image006.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></td>
            <td width="97%" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:left;"> 000 000 000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><img alt="fax" src="/image008.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:left;"> 000 000 000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><img alt="cell" src="/image0010.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:left;"> 000 000 000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="middle"><img alt="email" src="/image0012.png" height="18" width="19" style="display: inline; vertical-align:middle;" valign="middle"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;font-size: 11pt; display: inline; white-space: nowrap; text-align:left;"> name@web.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;display: inline; font-size: 11pt; padding-top:20px;"><b>Company Name</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;display: inline; font-size: 11pt">address</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;display: inline; font-size: 11pt">00000000000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a style="font-family:'Calibri light', sans-serif;color:black; text-decoration:none; display: block;" href="http://www.web.com"><span style="display: inline; font-size: 11pt;"><b>www.web.com</b></span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers

Comment: ok I recode everything and works great but not on iOS. I have unwanted space between every <tr>

Comment: Try display block on all the images.

Comment: Is there CSS in the head in your signature or just the html I pasted here?

Comment: I am using css inline like you. This is my head: <head>
    <meta media="screen" type="text/css">
</head>

Comment: Can u attach a screenshot for me? Also try `tr{padding:0px !Important; margin:0px !important;}` try that on all tr and if it's not fixed then add the screenshot.

Comment: Nothing. But I've prepared jsFiddle with full code https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/4mbmL48a/ and this is screenshot how it looks on iOS http://imgur.com/a/eovgl

Comment: Don't use row span or column span. Place a table with two columns and place both the image (left) and signature details on the right column. You have given it the left TD a height, remove that as well. Note you have added to what the original question/requirement was.

Comment: Without column span, row span I have problem with height - text isn't equally to image. I am fighting with this almost 4 days

Comment: Col and row span are rhe things causing problems. The original code i sent had evrrything working. When you have two columns the right one should have valign top. The table will align to the top on the right column.

Comment: I pasted your code into outlook app and looks good on web but on iOS. See this screen http://imgur.com/a/VWVaI

Comment: i have collaborated on the fiddle and fixed the issues you had. You HTML had a few errors that i fixed.https://jsfiddle.net/defuseer/4mbmL48a/#&togetherjs=13RIwhT8zx